# Combine 2 columns based on the value of one of them in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Education'] = df['Husband_Education'].astype(str) + df['Husband_Black']`I want to combine some of the value in one column with the content of another column in python. The column has values of : "yes", "No", and "Years". I only want to migrate all "years value to another column" my data looks like this :

My data :

```
+--------------------+---------------+
| Husband_education  | Husband black |
+--------------------+---------------+
| less than 12           years       |
+--------------------+---------------+
| 12 -15 years       | No            |
+--------------------+---------------+
| 12-15 years        | yes           |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

Desired Output :

```
+--------------------+---------------+
| Husband_education  | Husband black |
+--------------------+---------------+
| less than 12 years |     ---       |
+--------------------+---------------+
| 12 -15 years       | No            |
+--------------------+---------------+
| 12-15 years        | yes           |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

I want all words equal to "years" to move to the first column and keep values of "Yes" and "No " in the second column, I have 3,772 rows

my code looks like this any ideas?

`for row in df['Husband_Black']:
    if 'years' in row :
        df['Husband_Education'] = df['Husband_Education'].astype(str) + df['Husband_Black']`

Comment: It s unclear what you want to accomplish. Please include an example of the expected results.

Comment: provide expected output and your efforts what you tried and didn't work out.

Comment: I added the out put before the code , kindly review my post

Answer (score 0):

**I only want to migrate all "years value to another column" my data looks like this** What I understood from this is the value followed by year should only migrate to another column: There is a bad but easy value to extract years value:

```
# read your data line by line.
data = open("yourdatafile","r")
counter = 1
column ={}
for line in data:
   year_record = []
   # split by year
   line= line.split('years')
   # your example becomes ['Husband_education Husband black less than 12 
   #', ' 12-15 ', ' No 12-15 ', ' yes']
   #  now record the value 
   temp = line[0]
   year_record.append(temp[-1])
   year_record.append([line[1])
   temp = line[2]
   year_record.append([temp[1])
   # Record this record_value to the respective column 
   column[counter] = year_record 
   counter =counter +1
```

Comment: I have a data frame with 6 columns , I want to copy from the 3rd column to the second

Comment: Can u give an example what exactly u want? If you just want to copy from 3rd column to 2nd, use panda. Imprt pandas as pd, put your problem into data frame pd.DataFrame. and then simply copy df['3rd'] = df['2nd'], where 3rd and 2nd are your columns.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, I was able to use np and take the whole dataframe in one line instead of iterating :

```
    df['Husband_Education'] = np.where(df['Husband_Black']=='years',  df['Husband_Education'].map(str) + ' ' +'years', df['Husband_Education'])
```